# Why when coloring the first columns[0] cells in dataGridView1 it's not coloring the first cell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

```
for (int i = 0; i < countriesCodes.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Status";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Country";
                var countryName = codeToFullNameMap[countriesCodes[i]];
                string[] row = new string[] { "Ready", countryName };
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
                dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
                dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
                dgvLink.HeaderText = "Link Data";
                dgvLink.Name = "SiteName";
                dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
                dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
                dgvLink.Text = lines[i];
                dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
            }
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;

            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;


            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

The last line should color the cells under the first column:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

If i change it to Columns[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxN6m.jpg) it will color all cells in Red. But when it's Columns[0] the first cell under Status(in the screenshot) is still in black.

[image: Still black]

The word Ready the first word Ready under Status is in black. Can't figure out why it's not coloring it too. If i color the cells under Columns[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxN6m.jpg) it will color all the cells but i want to color the those under Status in Columns[0]

Comment: Maybe because it's selected?

Comment: The code order is pretty busted in general.  This went wrong because the code changed the default cell style *after* it already added the row.  So inevitably the first row used the old cell style.  A lot of this code needs to be moved in front of the for(;;) loop, anything that configures the DGV.

Answer (score 2):

If you move selected cell to another `cell`, you will see that the item is also has red `forecolor`. These two lines overrides Selection colors. Comment them or give something logical to avoid confusion.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
```

Edit 1:

For the problem that you commented about, Set them transparent.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Commenting this two lines fix the problem in my question but bring up my problem before that the this first cell is selected i mean is in highlight like i clicked on it. Thats why i added this two lines since this lines was the only working wolution to remove the highlight. Now the highlight is back but it's in red if i click/select another cell.

Comment: Almost. Now the first cell is blank empty only if i click on it select it i will see the text inside but then it's not in red.

Comment: Okay, put this `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = false;` @DanielHalfoni

Comment: The only thing that is working is this: DataGridViewCellStyle mystyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            mystyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
            mystyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = mystyle; I tried all other solutions including CurrentCell.Selected false and only this is working so far.

Comment: Whats wrong after all the solutions that I gave? Can you provide output? Or setting defaultcellstyle completely solved your problem? @DanielHalfoni

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem. I solved it by adding a condition to my "For" cycle. In your case, you will need to enter:

```
if(i == 0)
   {
    countriesCodes.Colums[0].Selected = false;
   }
```

I believe that the lack of coloring is due to an incorrect coloring of the **selection of the cells**